# How do i disable the ability to deselect a record on a WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working on implementing a WPF Datagrid and I have a requirement where a record in the grid must always be selected.  I have set the `SelectionMode=Single` and `SelectionUnit=FullRow`.  However if i click and drag a given record while pressing control i am able to enter a state where the grid no longer has a selected value.  It looks like by pressing control i am able to get the record to deselect.  I have tried handling the preview key down event and setting handled to true when the control key is pressed but it seems to be an order of operations issue between click/dragging the records and the control key being pressed.  Ultimately i would like to just disable the whole click/drag the grid selection, but i am coming up short on that one.  I am trying to keep this as clean as possible.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What happens when you set e.Handled = false in the Selection Changed event?

Comment: Nothing.  The selection has already changed at that point.  It doesn't really help me at all. Is there something specific you were getting at?

Comment: I suppose you can cache the selected item. Then when another event happens which sets the selected item to null, you can reset the grid's selected item back to the cached value.